# How can i start ubuntu side by side with windows 7 32bit?

Tags: windows-xp

Need help how can I work on ubuntu but also have windows?

Comment: Search a bit before asking question

Answer (score 0):

Go for a dual boot. Choose install Ubuntu side by side option when installing if you don't have a separate partition. Use something else option if you have a separate partition to install Ubuntu. Lastly, install grub in MBR. Hope it helps.

Remember to install Windows first to avoid difficulties and if you are newly partitioning a hard drive, create 3 partitions, one NTFS for Windows, one EXT4 for Ubuntu and one NTFS for data, that can be accessed by both the OS. Choose don't use this partition option for the data partition when you install Ubuntu.

Comment: The question is a tad unclear, but I think the OP is asking if he can have Windows and Ubuntu running at the same time (side by side) and switch between them easily, presumably without rebooting. IThough 'd think, that's not possible except in a virtual machine